# Rails i18n translates key instead of raising "translation missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Searching for hours but cannot find the solution.
I have a translation key:

```json
en:
  welcomes
    index:
      welcome: Hello World!
```

Using I18n's "lazy loading" I can use `<%= t('.welcome') %>` which works perfectly fine.

However, when I do something like:

```rb
# in welcomes/index.html.erb
<%= t('.welcome_abc') %>
```

I expect a "translation missing" to be presented but instead it translates to "Welcome Abc".

I cannot find a setting at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html that creates this behaviour.

How do I get the "translation missing" error here?

**SOLUTION!**

Apparently there still is a missing key.

According to https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/translate when there is a `MissingTranslation` it will render an inline span that contains "the missing key as the value of the title attribute"

Welcome Abc

Comment: Doing the same thing in my app (adjusted for my locale file) gives the desired error. You might have some gem or similar that is intercepting things and providing this functionality?

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I found the answer and update my post.

Comment: Oh, I checked in the console, not in a view. Good find.